# pyplot output doesn't look right

Tags: python, seaborn

First question asked here. I hope i do it right. Please let me know if i should provide more info or if my question is not clear.

I am trying to use python (pandas, seaborn, matplotlib) to generate a line graph. After much playing around, the script runs but the output doesn't look right. The raw data is a lot smoother than it appears on the output of my script. I've compared it to a graph generated in excel, which looks much more realistic. I don't really understand whats going wrong with my script.

The dataset is daily closing market prices for "RBD Palm Olein FOB Malaysia". Column 1 is date, column 2 is price. The data is saved as a CSV. The only issue i can think of is the missing days for when the market is closed. Could that be the issue?

The code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/michaelkingston/Desktop/RBDP2015_20.csv")
print(df)
df.info()
df['ds']= pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
df.info()
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x="ds",
        y="Y",
        data=df)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
```

here is an image of the excel output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85h0h.png)

here is the python output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skgiG.png)

```
print(df.head)

<bound method NDFrame.head of              ds    Y
0    2015-02-01  673
1    2015-05-01  663
2    2015-06-01  663
3    2015-07-01  668
4    2015-08-01  680
...         ...  ...
1419 2020-10-23  775
1420 2020-10-26  805
1421 2020-10-27  810
1422 2020-10-28  828
1423 2020-10-29  825
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample data and the output you are getting with your code and what do you expect.

Comment: hi, i edited the comment to show the excel graph output and the python graph output. I'm sorry i don't know how to upload the .csv file for the dataset

Comment: can you at least show us df.head() ? Just paste it here as if it were code.

Comment: Hello, i've updated to include print(df.head). I hope thats helpful. You can see that there are effectively null values for the non-trading days (eg 2015-03-01, 2015-04-01). I suspect that this might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel your output is correct according to the data and it is different from what you are getting in excel since the python's plot is squeezed to the default plot size and you can resize the plot to stretch it as you got in excel.
Another point is: if you need the x-axis labels as you have in excel then it's better you don't convert the date column to datetime object since while plotting datetime objects matplotlib shows only a few dates to ensure readability.

Here's what you can try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    

#converting the column ds to string type    
df['ds'] = df['ds'].astype(str)    

#fixing a big figure size for the plot    
plt.figure(figsize=(25,10))

sns.lineplot(x="ds", y="Y", data=df)

#for making the x-axis labels rotate by 90 degree to avoid cluttering of tick labels    
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I will give it a try

Comment: thank you @Arvind Kumar, That fixed the problem. The output now looks correct. Thank you for your help. Its much appreciated

Comment: I'm glad it helped.